# Error on converting enum from Typescript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I have an enum in Typescript let's say

```
export const enum CarType {
    SED = "Sedan"
}
```

The JavaScript code after build :

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports,"_esModule, { value: true })
```

:

So basically the js code doesn't  have the logic, instead only the .d.ts file has the same.
When I build it using `tsc` command and export the JavaScript code to a react app, while accessing this enum like: `CarType.SED`, it is giving an error like - `Cannot read property SED of undefined`

What could be the reason for the same. I understood that the typescript has a declaration file(of extension .ts). How can I use this in a purely JS project?

Comment: You should probably post your javascript code as well

Comment: @Florian, added the JS code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documenation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> Const enums can only use constant enum expressions and **unlike regular enums they are completely removed during compilation.** Const enum members are inlined at use sites. This is possible since const enums cannot have computed members.

Removing the `const` keyword should work. The inlining can only work if you use the enum in another TypeScript file.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the compiler option ([TSC options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)) "preserveConstEnums" as true:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Or command line:

```
tsc --preserveConstEnums true path/to/some_file.ts
```

[constant enum spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#94-constant-enum-declarations)